# EF Code First composite key mapping

Tags: ef-code-first

I have 2 tables. User and Roles.One user can have meany roles. so i created another table called RoleUser. how should i implement this in code first(i want to insert and update operation)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Natively you should be able to declare the two tables (with properties pointing to the other) and EF will pick up on the many-to-many relationship (and create the intermediary table with two FK's)

```
public class user
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }

    // user can be within multiple roles
    public ICollection<role> roles { get; set; }
}
public class role
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    // role can have many users
    public ICollection<user> users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: i can add data to  intermediary table(Role_User) but update does not work